# How to use Process to count how many records have checkbox that equals true?

Tags: formula, formula-field

How to use a Process to count how many records have checkbox that equals true? OR even a formula field.

'Request for Meeting Bonus' is a checkbox on Event that I need to count and have a SUM of for a calendar month.

I am not a Developer, but I do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Where do you need the output? It seems like the most obvious answer here is to write a report and export the data onto a dashboard. However if you want to roll up the count onto parent accounts for example, then Andy Fawcett's [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B45gWEAR) is probably what you're after.